# Send request to local printer from my public server

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I enabled port forwarding on my router to redirect the requests to my printer but I don't know how I can validate that the request are coming from my server.(My router does not have a built in firewall for incoming traffic).

Answer (score 0):

You cant - unless you modify the way you do things which you absolutely need to do.

If your router can act as a VPN server, rather then port forwarding require a VPN connection whivh can somewhat meet the authentication requirement.